# Insert data from 2 table to another table sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I need help regarding insert multiple data from 2 table to one table. the data will be from another table. I have tables below.

```
 table a
 id   word  status
 12    test   ok
 13    test2  ook
 14    test3  ok

 table b
 id    synonyms  status
 30     abc        ok
 31     abcd       ok
 32      ccc       ok
 35      ddd       ok  
 36     eeee       ok    

 table results
 id searchwordid searchsynonimid status
  1   12            30            ok
  2   12            34            ok
  3   12            33            ok
```

I need insert table results from `table a` and `table b`. on data/id in table a have some data in `table b`. my problem is when insert data, how to automatically add `searchwordid` field when have multiple data. I do `SELECT UNION ALL query`. the value will be get from dynamic field, dynamic field is for table b, but for table a just have one field.

all query must be run onetime when press submit button. really need helps.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your friend:

```
INSERT INTO table_c SELECT * FROM table_a,table_b;
```

For further information take a look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the clause row_number() could help you, using like this:

```
select row_number() over(order by a.id), a.id, b.id, b.status
from tablea a, tableb b
where b.synonyms = 'somethig'
and a.word = 'else'
group by a.id, b.id, b.status
```